# Split an amount in function of a startdate and a duration of month (In SQL Server/SSASTabular/PowerBi)

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

I have a table calendar :

[image]

and a table Offer

[image]

I want to create a measure Sum of amount, filter per StartDate and split per DurationOfMonth.

For example :
if i have

Amount -> 100$

StartDate -> 2021-02-18

DurationOfMonth -> 5

In PowerBi, I will have :

[image]

I was thinking about creating a new table in SQL Server which will be link to offer table  and duplicate the line per DurationOfMonth (Something like this)

[image]

But i was wondering if there is an easier methods (in dax or in SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best method but finally i just created a new view with the table calendar (Then i link with the table offer and create my measure) :

Something like this :

```
Create View  OfferDetails
AS
SELECT IIF(duration= 0 ,amount, CASt(amount as decimal)/ (duration+1)), CalendarDate
FROM  Offer offe
INNER JOIN (SELECT YEAR,MonthOfYear,MAX(CalendarDate) CalendarDate FROM Calendar GROUP BY Year, MonthOfYear) cal 
ON cal.CalendarDate BETWEEN EOMONTH(offe.StartDate) AND  EOMONTH(DateAdd(MONTH,offe.duration,offe.StartDate))
```